# creating a sphere from 2d coords using sine and cosine

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

what. I'm to achieve is to have an array of 2d coordinates and mapping them to the 3d surface of a sphere. To figure out how to do this I have an array of xy coordinates

I'm using the following loops to generate 20*20 xy coordinates from 0 to 1 on each axis:

```
var plot = []

for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
for (var ii = 0; ii <= 20; ii++) {
    plot.push({
        x: ii/20,
        y: i/20
    })
}
}
```

then I go through the array and translate the xy values to xyz values:

```
for (var i = 0; i < plot.length; i++) {
points.push({
    x: Math.sin(plot[i].x*(6.283185307)) * Math.sin(plot[i].y * Math.PI),
    y: plot[i].y * 2,
    z: Math.cos(plot[i].x*(6.283185307)) * Math.sin(plot[i].y * Math.PI)

});
}
```

I have 2 problems:

- I have to use 6.2831.. because Math.sin(Math.PI*2) doesn't return 0
- the sphere which is returned is wonky on the y axis:

[image: hi mom]

Comment: `Math.sin(Math.PI*2)` = `-2.4492935982947064e-16`, `Math.sin(6.283185307)` = `-1.7958636867904636e-10`. Math.PI*2 is closer to 0 than 6.283185307

Comment: Also you can write `Math.sin ( angle % ( Math.PI * 2 ) )` that will then return 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got is the rotation of half a sine wave around the `y` axis, with horizontal radius of `sin(y*pi/2)` for `y in 0..2`. Thus the pointed ends at north and south pole.

---

The coordinates should be, using `u=plot[i].x * 2*Math.PI`, `v=plot[i].y * Math.PI`

```
x : sin(u)*sin(v)
y : cos(v)
z : cos(u)*sin(v)
```

this will give you points on the unit sphere. Your concern about `Math.sin(Math.PI*2)` is unfounded, I'd expect `Math.sin(6.283185307)` to be farther away from zero, since the argument is a worse approximation of `2*pi`. (As confirmed by the actual values in the comment of Tomasz Jakub Rup.)

Answer (score 1):

In some applications is necessary to make sure the points match exactly. For instance if you want to build a mesh of the sphere without boundary. In such a case you might need to treat the boundary points separately.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    for (var ii = 0; ii <= 20; ii++) {
        theta = 2* Math.PI * i /20;
        phi = Math.PI * ii / 20;

        if(ii==0)   // North Pole
            points.push( {x:0; y:1, z:0} )
        else if(ii==20)   // South Pole
            points.push( {x:0; y:-1, z:0} )
        else if(i== 0 || i == 20) // 0º longitude
            points.push({ x: 0,
                y: Math.cos(phi),
                z: Math.sin(phi) } )
        else
            points.push({ x: Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi),
                y: Math.cos(phi),
                z: Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(phi) });
     }
}
```

You could consider adding cases for the equator and 90º, 180º, 270º longitude if exact coordinates are important.